# Installing WP twice in same Directory?

Tags: multisite, installation

I have a website that has Wordpress installed in the root directory `/`

I have another website, that's contents is within that root directory, `/seperatesite/` that stores a separate, small, splash page type website, with a separate domain pointing to it.

I want to setup another Wordpress install inside of this folder. Is it hazardous to have two Wordpress installs setup this way? I'm wondering as I currently don't have the host credentials to create a separate database within the host area if need be, is this simple enough to move without this - or still a sensitive setup?

**Thanks for any pointers!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered setting your main site to a multisite setup?

This would allow you to use the same wordpress files from the root and serve a wordpress site under the `/seperatesite/` directory without the need for duplicating files.

take a look at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

If you need any specific help regarding setting this up then feel free to make a new question.